# PHP: Undefined index notice when redirecting search results to new page

Tags: php, session

My website has a search function which works fine - only now I want the search results to be displayed on a new page (and not the same page). To this end I made use of the global variable `$_SESSION` (to make the array available in the new location) and `header("Location:` to redirect to the dedicated page for results.

On running the search, the following errors are generated:

- Notice: Undefined index: search_output in final.php on line 12
- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in final.php on line
  12

It's the first time I'm using $_SESSION and don't know how to fix these errors.
Would appreciate any insight in understanding what's wrong.

Here are the pages:
**index.php**

```
<?php require_once  ('setup.php');
require_once  ('function.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
  $search_results='';
  $search_term = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_results = search($conn, $search_term);  
  }
?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
                <label>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="searchitem" name="s">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">              
</form>

  <?php if (isset($search_results)) : 
        $_SESSION['search_output'] = $search_results;
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit;
   endif; ?>

<body>
</html>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php

function search($conn, $search_term) {
   if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }
    $sanitized =  $conn->real_escape_string($search_term);

    $query = $conn->query("
      SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR body LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR sources LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR date LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'");


    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }


    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }


  ?>
```

**final.php**

```
<?php session_start();  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
     echo $value['results']->title;
}
?>

<body>
</html>
```

**setup.php**

```
<?php
$hn = 'localhost';
$db = 'boh';
$un = 'water';
$pw = 'water'; 

#DB Connection:
 $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
 if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
?>
```

Comment: where is setup.php ?

Comment: just start the session if its null before using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined index: search_output in final.php on line 12

You need to use `session_start();` in **index.php** file on top level. so start your session you will resolve the Undefined index issue.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in final.php on line
>   12

For second issue, you can use like that:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['search_output']) && is_array($_SESSION['search_output']))
{
    foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value)
    {
       echo $value['results']->title;
    }
}
?>
```

---

You also need some modification in function.php file as:

```
function search($conn, $search_term) {
    $sanitized =  $conn->real_escape_string($search_term);

    $query = $conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM news WHERE 
    title (LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR body LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' 
        OR sources LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' 
        OR date LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'"));

    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
        return false;
    }

    $rows = array(); // ADD THIS
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $search_results = array(
        'count' => $query->num_rows,
        'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

After discussion with OP, you need to modify your final.php file, because you have another loop inside the results index in `$_SESSION['search_output']`, so final implementation should be:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['search_output']) && is_array($_SESSION['search_output']))
    {
       foreach($_SESSION['search_output']['results'] as $value){
       echo $value->title;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: am getting the same errors for the variable in the loop in final.php.

Comment: echo $value['results']['title']; you can get like that its an array @AgniScribe

Comment: @AgniScribe: or still same than just share the result of print_r($_SESSION['search_output']); before foreach loop

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION['search_output']);` outputs the right result, but `echo $value['results']['title'];` gives the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: results in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\final.php on line 14`

Comment: just share the result of print_r($_SESSION['search_output'], @AgniScribe

Comment: `Array ( [count] => 1 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [newstrack] => 6 [title] =>STUDENTS IN FOR A TREAT AT GALA ......`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103193/discussion-between-devpro-and-agni-scribe).

Comment: yes, `$_SESSION['search_output']['results']` was the key. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not used session_start() in setup.php nor function.php

You should start sesstion before using $_SESSION variable, use below code to start session,

```
 if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }
```

Comment: the undefined index error remains, along with `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 13` (same line in final.php)

Comment: $search_results is an array

Comment: It gives the digit: '1'

Comment: `print_r($search_results)` is outputting the correct result. so i think there's something with the session or the variable?

Comment: added in every file, same errors: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object & Notice: Undefined index: results  (same line of final.php: echo $value['results']->title;)

Comment: yes, it prints out the correct result. i think the error has to do with the way I'm accessing the right value from the $value array

Comment: (srry, power cut) - did that, it just doubles the same errors for the new variable

Comment: @AgniScribe: did u checked my answer?